# how to append Pandas series with same indexes?

Tags: python, append, series

if we have two pandas series like this:

```
s=pd.Series(["john","jack"],index=[0,1])
t=pd.Series(["elie","mary"], index=[0,1])
```

which results s:

```
0    john
1    jack
dtype: object
```

and t:

```
0    elie
1    mary
dtype: object
```

if we append s and t in a way like this:

```
s.append(t)
```

what's the result of

```
s.loc[1]
```

Comment: I would suggest testing it and find out. If you already have and have questions about what you are seeing it would be better if you actually post those questions rather than something you can test outright.

Comment: Have you tried this? What was the output? What is your expected output?

Comment: Your question reads like an exam question, did you try this? Are you asking why it works like this or are you trying to achieve something?

Comment: @scrappedcola , @hoffee @EdChum it seems that my question is much ambiguous. I meant if `e=s.append(t)` It's expected to have both **mary** and **jack** with index=1 in `e`, so if I get `e.loc[1]` which one is reasonable to be the output. **mary** or **jack** and why?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to obtain:

```
0    john    elie
1    jack    mary
```

Then try :

```
new_df = pd.join(s, t, left_index=True, right_index=True)
```